# Operating System State Diagram

Tags: operating-system, state, diagram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [State transition diagram for reader writer problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524262/state-transition-diagram-for-reader-writer-problem)

```
Counter | Write Flag |  Read Flag | Description
________|____________|____________|________________
   0    |      0     |     0      | Write Locked
   0    |      0     |     1      | Invalid
   0    |      1     |     0      | Invalid
   0    |      1     |     1      | Available
n(n>0)  |      0     |     0      | Write Request
n(n>0)  |      0     |     1      | Read Lock
n(n>0)  |      1     |     0      | Invalid
n(n>0)  |      1     |     1      | Invalid
_____________________________________________________
```

Above are the state descriptions. Draw a state transition diagram
including all the valid states with edges labeled with appropriate
events that trigger the state transition. 
Also, describe why the invalid states are invalid.

Can you help me by telling me which would represent my states and maybe try to describe how my drawing would be and how to do my transitions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Doing the same course as Luron eh?  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6524262/469210

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you know how to draw DFAs.  Here's a hint: you have 8 possible states, they're listed on your table.  Draw a big circle for each one of them, and label them however you feel like (but the "Description" column seems like a decent idea).  Then, draw arrows in between them describing how you go from one state to the other.  For example, you might go from `Available` to `Read Lock` when a thread demands a read lock.